# Isolation transformer Confusion

Tags: transformer, electrical

I’m  hoping someone can clear up some confusion.I understand how an earth reference transformer works and how if there was an earth fault there would be a large rush of current through ground and back to loop causing a fuse to melt or MCB to trip and a residual circuit device. I understand how the ac works where you would have +230 with electrons flowing towards higher potential and then on the negative part of cycle electrons flow the opposite direction again to higher potential with neutral having no voltage. Now my confusion lies with isolation transformers with floating leads.

Can someone  explain to me what voltage is where on the two hot leads on an isolation transformer? Is it +230 through one and -230 through the other at same time. Is it shared? I’m confused.
The diagram included (taken from another post) illustrates an isolation transformer with no reference to ground. I know that in order to get a shock I would have to (and foolishly) make contact with both leads on some part of my body to create a loop and get a shock, touching one and ground wouldn’t shock me. So how does electricity flow on floating sensors? With no loop created back to source how is current flowing through those lamps?
Clearly I’m missing something and hope someone can explain.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3):

The ground symbol is misleading. The lamps are connected to each other. This completes the circuit from one side of the transformer to the other. This illuminates both lamps in series.

If only one lamp is connected then nothing would happen.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fteFFS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is what the effective circuit looks like.

As far as the voltage after the transformer, you have to pick a reference yourself. But now you only have two choices. One wire is the reference and the other is hot. The hot wire goes +230 then -230 then +230 when compared to the reference.

Comment: Thanks vini_i that does make sense. Where does that centre wire between two lamps terminate? Also can you shed light on what the voltage is doing as per the other part to my question? I’m studying plumbing and would like to learn all about electricity as well.

Comment: Where does that center wire between two lamps terminate? Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I meant the line with triangle on end

Comment: That's just what I used to symbolize the ground you had before.

Comment: Ah I got you. I see what you mean now

Comment: Oi! @vini_i: "*The ground symbol is misleading.*" That's [my diagram](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405571/using-a-residual-current-device-when-there-is-an-isolation-transformer/405575#405575) you're referring to. I deliberately chose the **earth** symbol as it refers to mains earth rather than an arbitrary circuit ground. Your alternate layout seems to have made it clear to the OP, however, so that's fine. My layout is a reduction of a [three-phase fault indicator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323650/3-phase-delta-with-ground-reference/323659#323659).

Comment: @Transistor I guess that I should clarify that my misleading refers to that the bulbs don't flow current to ground while there is no fault that is. They use the ground as a connection point.

Comment: @vini: That's true when all is well. Their purpose is to show earth faults at other points in the circuit. When an earth fault occurs somewhere on the secondary side then one of the lights will glow brightly while the other turns off. Current will flow through the earth connections.